# ntrSetting the value of select from database in blade Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, select

I'm trying to display the value of select in my `blade.php` that is coming from `database`. 
Assuming that the `schedule` from database is Sunday, I want it to be displayed as the selected option in `select`

```
<select name="new_dayoff" id="new_dayoff" class="form-control" required>
      <option disabled selected value="">--Select Dayoff--</option>
      <option value="SUN">Sunday</option>
      <option value="MON">Monday</option>
      <option value="TUE">Tuesday</option>
      <option value="WED">Wednesday</option>
      <option value="THU">Thursday</option>
      <option value="FRI">Friday</option>
      <option value="SAT">Saturday</option>
</select>
```

Here's my Controller:

```
     $sched = Schedule::where('emp_id', $id)->first();
    return view('admin.employee', compact('sched'));
```

I don't think the `value` works.

Comment: add your controller code and query you tried

Comment: please take a look at it @Karan

Answer (score 0):

Just add `selected="selected"` attribute when the `$value` variable is equal to the `value` attribute

```php
<select name="new_dayoff" id="new_dayoff" class="form-control" required>
      <option disabled @if(!$value) selected @endif value="">--Select Dayoff--</option>
      <option @if($value == 'SUN') selected @endif value="SUN">Sunday</option>
      <option @if($value == 'MON') selected @endif value="MON">Monday</option>
      <option @if($value == 'TUE') selected @endif value="TUE">Tuesday</option>
      <option @if($value == 'WED') selected @endif value="WED">Wednesday</option>
      <option @if($value == 'THU') selected @endif value="THU">Thursday</option>
      <option @if($value == 'FRI') selected @endif value="FRI">Friday</option>
      <option @if($value == 'SAT') selected @endif value="SAT">Saturday</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to add `selected` attribute in `<option>`

```php
<select name="new_dayoff" id="new_dayoff" class="form-control" required>
    <option disabled value="">--Select Dayoff--</option>
    <option value="SUN" {{ $sched->new_dayoff=="SUN"?'selected:""}}>Sunday</option>
    <option value="MON" {{ $sched->new_dayoff=="MON"?'selected:""}}>Monday</option>
    <option value="TUE" {{ $sched->new_dayoff=="TUE"?'selected:""}}>Tuesday</option>
    <option value="WED" {{ $sched->new_dayoff=="WED"?'selected:""}}>Wednesday</option>
    <option value="THU" {{ $sched->new_dayoff=="THU"?'selected:""}}>Thursday</option>
    <option value="FRI" {{ $sched->new_dayoff=="FRI"?'selected:""}}>Friday</option>
    <option value="SAT" {{ $sched->new_dayoff=="SAT"?'selected:""}}>Saturday</option>
</select>
```